# How to insert value on a hidden input Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

trying to add date to date picker, date picker updating the value to a hidden field when we enter our date

The page's source code looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" 
  name="fields[1].content" 
  value="" 
  id="fields1contenthidden">
```

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079040/selenium-python-how-to-insert-value-on-a-hidden-input) answer but not worked for me,I'm using Selenium's WebDriver and coding in Python.

i am looking for value like this

```
<input type="hidden" 
  name="fields[1].content" 
  value="2018-05-02" 
  id="fields1contenthidden">
```

Comment: share your code with a traceback error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium (Python): How to insert value on a hidden input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079040/selenium-python-how-to-insert-value-on-a-hidden-input)

Comment: not a duplicate already mention in question, dont mark as a duplicate

Comment: just by taking this code in a browser the code in link provided work. Can you provide link to the site (if not private) or more html code?